# How to check if an item exists in an Elixir list or tuple?

Tags: elixir

This is seemingly simple, but I can't seem to find it in the docs. I need to simply return `true` or `false` if an item exists in a list or tuple. Is `Enum.find/3` really the best way to do this?

```
Enum.find(["foo", "bar"], &(&1 == "foo")) != nil
```

Comment: For a list I could see where you want to just see if the item is there in which Enum.member?/2 would be a good.

But for a tuple you usually care about the position of the value, that is one of the beauties of tuples... might want to consider the usage of a tuple if you don't care about position

Comment: You may want to mark @Gazler's answer as the accepted answer if it's right.

Comment: Quick note about performance. The `x in y` guard is very performant because it creates different function definitions at compile time. At runtime it's less performant, equivalent to `Enum.member?`, though they're fine to use for small _n_. For large _n_ and tight loops, you'll get better performance from something that hashes, such as `MapSet.member?`. But in most cases, `x in y` and `Enum.member?` are fine!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Based on the answers here and in Elixir Slack, there are multiple ways to check if an item exists in a list. 
Per answer by @Gazler:

```
Enum.member?(["foo", "bar"], "foo")
# true
```

or simply

```
"foo" in ["foo", "bar"]
# true
```

or

```
Enum.any?(["foo", "bar"], &(&1 == "foo")
# true
```

or if you want to find and return the item instead of `true` or `false`

```
Enum.find(["foo", "bar"], &(&1 == "foo")
# "foo"
```

If you want to check a tuple, you need to convert to list (credit @Gazler):

```
Tuple.to_list({"foo", "bar"})
# ["foo", "bar"]
```

But as @CaptChrisD pointed out in the comments, this is an uncommon need for a tuple because one usually cares about the exact position of the item in a tuple for pattern matching.

Answer (score 169):

You can use [**`Enum.member?/2`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#member?/2)

```
Enum.member?(["foo", "bar"], "foo")
# true
```

With a tuple you will want to convert to to a list first using [**`Tuple.to_list/1`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Tuple.html#to_list/1)

```
Tuple.to_list({"foo", "bar"})
# ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: Thanks Gazler. Your answer is correct, but I wanted to post a separate answer based on all of the suggestions I received around the community.

Comment: Note that you won't be able to use `Enum.member?/2` inside a guard. In that case, you'll have to rely on `in`. For example: `def foo(string) when string in ["one", "two"], do: IO.puts(string)`. By the way, this is funny, because `in` is a macro that translates to `Enum.member?/2` :D

Answer (score 37):

Or just use `in`:

```
iex(1)> "foo" in ["foo", "bar"]
true
iex(2)> "foo" in Tuple.to_list({"foo", "bar"})
true
```

Comment: This answer is like the only that answerds OP's question: "...exists in an elixir LIST"...not an enum.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`Enum.find_value/3`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#find_value/3) too:

```
iex(1)> Enum.find_value(["foo", "bar"],false, fn(x)-> x=="foo" end)
true

iex(2)> Enum.find_value(["foo", "bar"],false, fn(x)-> x=="food" end)
false
```

Answer (score 2):

I started programming in Elixir yesterday, but I will try something I did a lot in JS, maybe it is useful when the list has a lot of elements and you don't want to traverse it all the time using Enum.member?

```
map_existence = Enum.reduce(list,%{}, &(Map.put(&2,&1,true)))
map_existence[item_to_check]
```

You can also retrieve an intersection with some other list:

```
Enum.filter(some_other_list,&(map_existence[&1]))
```